# Confused about choosing a loop to iterate a linked list

Tags: java, linked-list

My problem is in the add method.  I think I know what I want it to do but I can't figure out what type of loop I should use to look through the list.  As you can see I started to make a if else loop but I couldn't figure out what I should use as the counter.  I'm pretty sure I have the right logic in dealing with the add but I feel like I'm not quite there yet.  I was thinking of using compareTo in some fashion.

```
import java.util.*;
public class OrderedLinkedList<E extends Comparable<E>>
{
   private Node topNode;
   private class Node
   {
       private E data;
       private Node nextNode;

       public Node(E data)
       {
           this.data = data;
           nextNode = null;
       }
   }
   public OrderedLinkedList()
   {
       topNode = null;
   }   

   public boolean empty()
   {
       if(topNode == null)
        return true;
       return false; 
   }    

   public String toString()
   {
       String myString = "";
       Node nextNode = topNode;
       while(nextNode != null)
       {
           myString = topNode + " -> " + nextNode;
           nextNode = topNode.nextNode;
       } 
       return myString;
   }    

   public void add(E data)
   {
       Node myNode = new Node(data);
       Node priorNode = topNode;
       Node currentNode = topNode;
       if(___)
       {
           priorNode = currentNode;
           currentNode = currentNode.nextNode;
       }
       else
       {
          priorNode.nextNode = myNode;
          myNode.nextNode = currentNode;
       }  
   }    

}
```

Comment: An `if` is not a `loop` of any kind.

Comment: I meant if else sorry

Comment: if else is also not a loop - loops are structures that repeat a set of actions based on whether a given condition evaluates to true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't typically know the length of a linked list until you've walked down it, the usual thing would be to use a while loop (as you've done in your toString() method)

Comment: I thought about that but how could I get it to stop at a certain point to add the new node in?

Comment: Well, it depends on what you know about that point. Maybe you want to add it at the end - then just "while next is not null" will do. On the other hand, if you're trying to maintain some sorted order, you could say "while the next node sorts less than the node to insert" - for example, if you have a list of "a" -> "c"-> "f" ->"q" and you want to insert "d", you'd look at "a", keep going, look at "c", "c"<"d" so advance, then "f">"d", so insert after "c". Clear?

Comment: I think so.  I could do something like while(nextNode.compareTo(newNode))

Comment: Yes, I think you've got the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using a doubly linked list would be more beneficial. Consider the following alterations to your class:

```
import java.util.*;
public class OrderedLinkedList<E extends Comparable<E>>
{
   private Node head;
   private Node tail;

   private class Node
   {
       private E data;
       private Node nextNode;
       private Node prevNode;

       public Node(E data)
       {
           this.data = data;
           nextNode = null;
           prevNode = null;
       }

       public void setNext(Node node)
       {
           this.nextNode = node;
       }

       public Node getNext()
       {
           return this.nextNode;
       }

       public void setPrev(Node node)
       {
           this.prevNode = node;
       }

       public Node getPrev()
       {
           return this.prevNode;
       }

       public E getData()
       {
           return this.data;
       }

       public int compareTo(Node that) {
           if(this.getData() < that.getData())
           {
               return -1;
           }
           else if(this.getData() == that.getData()
           {
               return 0;
           }
           else
           {
               return 1;
           }
       } 
   }

   public OrderedLinkedList()
   {
       head = new Node(null);
       tail = new Node(null);

       head.setNext(tail);
       tail.setPrev(head);
   }   

   public boolean empty()
   {
       if(head.getNext() == tail)
       {
           return true;
       }
       return false; 
   }

   public void add(E data) {
       Node tmp = new Node(data);

       if(this.empty()) {
           this.addNodeAfterNode(tmp, head);
       } else {
          Node that = head.getNext();

          // this while loop iterates over the list until finding the correct
          // spot to add the new node. The correct spot is considered to be
          // when tmp's data is >= that's data, or the next node after 'that'
          // is tail. In which case the node is added to the end of the list
          while((tmp.compareTo(that) == -1) && (that.getNext() != tail)) {
              that = that.getNext();
          }

          this.addNodeAfterNode(tmp, that);
       }
   }

   private void addNodeAfterNode(Node addNode, Node afterNode)
   {
       addNode.setNext(afterNode.getNext());
       afterNode.getNext().setPrev(addNode);
       afterNode.setNext(addNode);
       addNode.setPrev(afterNode);
   }

}
```